# Windows 8 laptop booting straight to BIOS. No logo

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, bios

One month old Windows 8 laptop (Asus K55N-DB81) has suddenly stopped booting. When turning on the laptop, it goes straight to BIoS without showing any of the ASUS logos or anything.

I've tried the following:

- Reset bios
- Pull RAM one at a time
- Boot without hard drive
- Try to use F12 boot options
- Make sure HDD and RAM are seated properly

All have no impact and have the same outcome as above. The BIOS seems to recognize that there is a hard drive and the proper amount of RAM.

I've exhausted all of my troubleshooting options. Anything else I can try before going through warranty support?

I should also note that the laptop came with no physical recovery media.

Comment: Check for a BIOS update.  It could be that there maybe an issue with that current version of your BIOS.

Comment: Ended up sending the laptop to Asus for warranty service. Thanks to all for the comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Windows installation disc or have the means to make one, you should try reinstalling Windows or repairing it from that disc.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Unfortunately I have no physical restore media. I will update my question.

Comment: @th3dude - Contact ASUS for the media in question.  You won't be able to fix the problem without it.

Answer (score 1):

Found this on the ASUS website.  Just check that I have your correct model.

```
BIOS 217
1．Update agesa code
2．Fix bug it will display ASUS logo when "Launch CSM" item disable
3．Fix the bug that System will show black screen
4. Fix winflash verify fail
```

[Asus](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K55N/#support)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this laptop was purchased in the last month and has the latest BIOS.